# Selector to a certain parameter as an input for a function

Tags: c#, .net, function, delegates

I have a class `Point`, which has several parameters.
Now I have a `List` of `Points` which goes into a certain function. As an input parameter I want to tell the function, which parameter it should use for a certain calculation.
Of course I could to something like

```
CalculateSomething(List<Point> points, List<double> points.Select(p => p.firstParameter))
```

but this is obviously not very smart, since in points `firstParameter` is already included.
Is there any way of just giving something like a `Selector`, telling the function, which parameter it should use.
Would be nice, if there is a way without an `enum` and then lots of `if`-cases or `switch-case`-structures.

```
using System;     
using System.Collections.Generic;  

public class Point
{
    public Point (...)
    { ... }

    public double x;
    public double y;

    public double firstParameter;
    public double secondParameter;
}            

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Point p1 = new Point(...);
        Point p2 = new Point(...);
        Point p3 = new Point(...);
        List<Point> points = new List<Point> { p1, p2, p3 };

        CalculateSomething(points, >>>SELECTOR<<<)
    }   

    public static double CalculateSomething(List<Point> points, >>>Selector selectedParameter<<<)
    {
        return points[0].x / points[0].y * points[0].selectedParameter;
    }   

}
```

Comment: What about storing the parameters in an array and pass the index as parameter in the method call ?

Comment: might be possible but doesn't sound very elegant ...

Comment: Well, you can use in class `Point` constants to define the index, such as `public const FirstParameter = 0;`, `public const SecondParameter = 1;`, `public const FooParameter = 2;`... And then `CalculateSomething(points, Point.FirstParameter);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method be like:

```
public static double CalculateSomething(List<Point> points, Func<Point, double> selector)
{
        return points[0].x / points[0].y * selector(points[0]);
}
```

And the call be like:

```
CalculateSomething(points, (p) => p.firstParameter);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double CalculateSomething(List<Point> points, Func<Point, double> selector)
{
    return points[0].x / points[0].y * selector(points[0]);
}
```

Then call like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Point p1 = new Point(...);
    Point p2 = new Point(...);
    Point p3 = new Point(...);
    List<Point> points = new List<Point> { p1, p2, p3 };

    CalculateSomething(points, point => point.firstParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.8) delegate for that

```cs
public static double CalculateSomething(List<Point> points, Func<Point, double> selector)
{
    return points[0].x / points[0].y * selector(points[0]);
}
```

And the usage example

```cs
Func<Point, double> selector = point => point.firstParameter;
CalculateSomething(points, selector);
```

or just

```cs
CalculateSomething(points, point => point.firstParameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Func<Point, double>` solution from the other answers is probably the cleanest method you'll find. It's doesn't do EXACTLY what you want, but it's readable, and shouldn't pose an issue assuming you or your code user has the faintest of code discipline.

If you REALLY want to say to your code "use that property" though, the only option you have is Reflection.

Note that this is just a thought experiment, and you probably shouldn't use such code lightly. It's not performance-friendly.

```
public static double CalculateSomething(List<Point> points, PropertyInfo pointProperty)
{
    return points[0].x / points[0].y * pointProperty.GetValue(points[0]);
}
```

Usage:

```
using System.Reflection;

/* ... */

CalculateSomething(points, typeof(Point).GetProperty("propertyName"));
```

Comment: I see the point of your statement! thanks for that comment. but I'll stay which the 2 other answers for reasons of simplicity :)

Comment: Yes, but if you were to do something like `CalculateSomething(points, point => 2)`, that's clear. By your method you could pass **any** `PropertyInfo` object and get a runtime exception.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Indeed! But at least you'd get an exception, which is what I'd expect if the provided parameter was invalid or didn't make sense here... like `point => 2` :) But again, this is just food for thoughts, and I only provided this answer for the sake of completeness; I don't caution actually using it.

Comment: No I'd want a compilation error rather than a runtime exception, when the parameters are 100% within your control. This allows the wrong type, wrong property type or even typos in the property name, which would not be picked up until runtime. I fail to see how this is helpful in any way. If the developer wants to use `point => 2` I can't see how that could be harmful.

Comment: It's harmful because it's actually a silent error. `point => 2` makes 0 sense, and it's going to pass as a successful behavior at runtime, while it should not be permitted at all. The only way to trace this error, once you realize your data is wrong at runtime, is to debug it. I'd also prefer a compilation error, but neither the `Func` nor my solution provides it.

Comment: It _may_ make sense dependent on the context; the developer has the flexibility to use a number from somewhere other than a property of `Point`. Either way, its no more silent than something like `int oneAddOne = 1 + 2;`, which could happen anywhere, and at least compilation checks haven't been bypassed.

Comment: Well, I'd like to avoid your `oneAddOne` exemple as well if possible, because it's also a silent "design" error (clarification). Can't avoid them all though. In the context of the question, the flexibility isn't needed.